# Markers' info window is not showing up after clicking on a Google pin

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I currently am generating markers from an events database. Upon clicking on a marker, an info window with the event's name and description. However, every time I click on Google maps pin (like a standard location such as the Eiffel tower) and then try to click on my markers, it won't display the info window anymore.

I tried adding clickable to the markers, but it doesn't change anything. Here's my current code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker, InfoWindow } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { getlocArray, retrieveListings } from './listings';

const containerStyle = {
  width: '600px',
  height: '600px',
};

const center = {
  lat: 34.0703,
  lng: -118.448,
};

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function MapsComponent() {
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
  const [selectedMarker, setSelectedMarker] = useState(null);
  const [listings, setListings] = useState([]);
  const [hasData, setHasData] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => { //simply loads in the events
    async function fetchData() {
      const data = await retrieveListings();
      setListings(data);
      const importedlocArray = await getlocArray();
      await sleep(150); 
      
      if (importedlocArray.length > 0) {
        setMarkers(
          importedlocArray.map((location, index) => ({
            key: index,
            position: {
              lat: location[1],
              lng: location[0],
            },
          }))
        );
      }
    }

    fetchData();
    setHasData(true);
  }, []);

  const handleMarkerClick = (marker) => {
    setSelectedMarker(marker);
  };

  const handleInfoWindowClose = () => {
    setSelectedMarker(null);
  };

  return (
    <>{hasData ? (
      <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey="API-key">
        <GoogleMap mapContainerStyle={containerStyle} center={center} zoom={15}>
          {markers.map((marker) => (
            <Marker
              key={marker.key}
              position={marker.position}
              clickable
              onClick={() => handleMarkerClick(marker)}
            />
          ))}
          {selectedMarker && (
            <InfoWindow
              position={selectedMarker.position}
              onCloseClick={handleInfoWindowClose}
            >
              <div>
                <h3>{listings[selectedMarker.key].title}</h3>
                <p>{listings[selectedMarker.key].description}</p>
              </div>
            </InfoWindow>
          )}
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>) : <p> Loading Events ... </p>}
    </>
  );
}

export default React.memo(MapsComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Enable `onClick` in the `<GoogleMap/>` component that would also set your `selectedMarker` state to `null`

before we proceed with the main answer, please note that if your use case of the `<InfoWindow />` component is to make it appear on top of a marker, you don't have to pass a `position` property as long as you render it inside the `<Marker />` component like so:

```
<Marker>
  <InfoWindow />
</Marker>
```

With that said, one thing to fix your issue is to include an `onClick` property in your `<GoogleMap />` component so that when you click on default map locations like the "Eiffel Tower" that you mentioned, your `selectedMarker` state should also be set to `null`. Because clicking those default Google Maps locations is basically clicking on the **map** itself.

So you can still use your `handleInfoWindowClose` callback function like so:

```
<GoogleMap
  mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
  center={center}
  zoom={15}
  onClick={handleInfoWindowClose}
>
```

If you also want to disable the Info Window of these default map locations from showing, you can also set the `clickableIcons` Map Option to `false`.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.clickableIcons

Since this is the `options` property of the `<GoogleMap />` component, you can set it up like so:

```
<GoogleMap
  mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
  center={center}
  zoom={15}
  onClick={handleInfoWindowClose}
  options={{
    clickableIcons: false
  }}
>
```

Now with regards to your `handleInfoWindowClose` callback function, it should look like this:

```
// You can use this same function with
// `onCloseClick` on the infoWindow and the `onClick` on the map
// to clear the `selectedMarker` state.
const handleInfoWindowClose = () => {
  if (selectedMarker != null) {
    setSelectedMarker(null);
    console.log(selectedMarker);
    console.log("Info window closed!");
  } else {
    console.log("No active Info Window");
  }
};
```

All in all, after doing some modification with your code to reproduce the expected behavior, your whole code should look something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  GoogleMap,
  LoadScript,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow
} from "@react-google-maps/api";

const containerStyle = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "100vh"
};

const center = {
  lat: 34.0703,
  lng: -118.448
};

const mapOptions = {
  clickableIcons: false
};

export default function MapsComponent() {
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
  const [selectedMarker, setSelectedMarker] = useState(null);
  const [hasData, setHasData] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // I just modified this to simulate the markers showing on map
    setMarkers([
      {
        key: 0,
        position: {
          lat: 34.0703,
          lng: -118.448
        }
      }
    ]);

    setHasData(true);
  }, []);

  const handleMarkerClick = (marker) => {
    // Just added this condition to prevent
    // the setSelectedMarker to run
    if (marker === selectedMarker) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(marker);
    setSelectedMarker(marker);
    console.log("Marker selected!");
  };

  // You can use this same function with
  // `onCloseClick` and the `onClick` on the map
  // to clear the `selectedMarker` state.
  const handleInfoWindowClose = () => {
    if (selectedMarker != null) {
      setSelectedMarker(null);
      console.log(selectedMarker);
      console.log("Info window closed!");
    } else {
      console.log("No active Info Window");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {hasData ? (
        <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey="">
          <GoogleMap
            mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
            center={center}
            zoom={15}
            onClick={handleInfoWindowClose}
            options={{
              clickableIcons: false
            }}
          >
            {markers.map((marker) => (
              <Marker
                key={marker.key}
                position={marker.position}
                onClick={() => handleMarkerClick(marker)}
              >
                {selectedMarker && (
                  <InfoWindow onCloseClick={handleInfoWindowClose}>
                    <div>
                      <h3>Title Here</h3>
                      <p>Description Here</p>
                    </div>
                  </InfoWindow>
                )}
              </Marker>
            ))}
          </GoogleMap>
        </LoadScript>
      ) : (
        <p> Loading Events ... </p>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Here's a proof of concept code sandbox for you to play around and check: https://codesandbox.io/s/enable-onclick-in-the-googlemap-component-that-would-also-set-your-selectedmarker-state-to-null-is4igs?file=/src/Map.js

I hope this helps!